# pop up Processing algorithm window from python console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

Is there a method for **just opening** a processing algorithm without running it?

I mean, with:

```
import processing
processing.runalg("qgis:countpointsinpolygon")
```

I have to add all the parameters required for the algorithm, and it throws an error.

What if I just want to open the dialog window of that algorithm?

Comment: @Joseph  Oh, I totally missed that answer. Exactly what I needed! Thanks